# How to run shell command in windows perl script

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I am running following command in windows perl:

```
qx(strings -a -f /cygdrive/C/TestBox/Out/UT_*.o | grep "Test_String");
```

I get an error: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. How to resolve this?

Comment: The command grep is probably not installed. Can you call grep from the cygwin console?

Comment: yes I am able to call grep from cygwin but i need to use the perl script in windows environment

Comment: Is your path set correctly to find 'grep'?  I have it installed at `/usr/bin/grep` on my Cygwin.  Are you running perl from within Cygwin?

Comment: Better to use the builtin Perl [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function.

Comment: This is a question that has 1. Nothing to do with programming in general; 2. Perl; 3. Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This code was apparently written on Unix or Linux by someone who didn't think that it might, someday, be used on a platform that doesn't have a `grep` command (like Windows).

And that's weird, because `grep`-like functionality is something that Perl is really good at. So it's hard to understand why they would rely on an external program that might not be installed.

I'd rewrite that line like this:

```
open my $string_fh, '-|', 'strings -a -f /cygdrive/C/TestBox/Out/UT_*.o' or die $!;
my @strings = grep { /Test_String/ } <$string_fh>;
```

I suppose there's also an argument for rewriting the `strings` call in pure Perl - but that wouldn't be quite so simple.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows perl (such as ActiveState or Strawberry Perl) will use the Windows shell to execute all `system` and `qx` commands, but it looks like you want to run some commands under the Cygwin shell. Some options:

1. Install and use `perl` on Cygwin. In Cygwin perl, the shell for `system` and `qx` commands is the Cygwin (bash) shell. Perl is easy to install from the setup program or to build from source.
2. Instruct Windows shell to run the command in the Cygwin shell. The command might look something like this (not tested):

   ```
   C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "strings -a -f /cygdrive/C/TestBox/Out/UT_*.o | grep 'Test_String'"
   ```